# Automatically Resize and adding of scrollbars based on inner content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I have this JQuery dialog that inside has JQuery tabs functionality. My problem is that I want to re-size and re-position the dialog based on the tab contents.

If the contents of the first tab fits or not the screen size I have this code that works pretty good (this refers to the dialog object):

```
if ($(this).parent().height() > $(window).height()) {
   $(this).height($(window).height() * 0.8);
}
$(this).dialog({
   position: "center"
});
```

If the contents of another tab is different, I want the dialog to redraw it self.

Here is an example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utvCr/).

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I would take this aproach for example:

```
       $(function () {
           $("#details-dialog").dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               height: "auto",
               minWidth: 500,//optional
               modal: true,
               buttons: {
                   "Close Window": function () {
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
               },
               open: function () {
                   $('#tabs1').tabs();
                   if ($(this).parent().height() > $(window).height()) {
                       $(this).height($(window).height() * 0.8);
                   }
                   $(this).dialog({
                       position: "center"
                   });
               },
               close: function () {}
           });


           $("#tabs1 a").click(function() {
               var size_id = $(this).attr("href");
              $("#details-dialog").parent().width($(size_id).width() + 100 );

              $("#details-dialog").dialog({
                 position: "center"
              });
            });

       });
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/utvCr/14/

Comment: I want to add scrollbars if the height is bigger that the screen size, and also re-possition in the center of the screen